# Get input text width when typing

Tags: javascript, html, css, input

I have a input type text

```
<input type="text" id="txtid">
```

When i start typing text inside input, i should be able to get the lenght of the entered text.

This is what I tried:

```
document.getElementById("txtid").offsetWidth;
```

and

```
var test = document.getElementById("txtid");
var width = (test.clientWidth + 1) + "px";
```

These two does not give the width of the text entered

Basically what I want is:

[image]

For suppose `input text` width is `320px`. I need the width of the entered text i.e `120px`, which keeps on changing when I enter.

Comment: I think this is not trivial. You could generate a invisible span which always contains  the same content as your inputbox. and then measure it's width.

Comment: Maybe you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21015393/4108884 as a workaround

Comment: There exists another dependency: The font it self. The width of each letter in every font have a different width. Even the letters have different width. In examplate: the 'i' is defnitly smaller than 'w'.

Comment: @Paflow Nice . better you could post the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate text width with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118241/calculate-text-width-with-javascript)

Comment: @the_lotus my question is specific to input text

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### I see two ways.

**First**:

You can use a div with content editable instead input. Like this you can see the width of the div.

```js
var elemDiv = document.getElementById('a');

elemDiv.onblur = function() {
  console.log(elemDiv.clientWidth + 'px');
}
```

```css
div {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id='a' contenteditable="plaintext-only">Test</div>
```

**Note** : Like @Leon Adler say, this way allows pasting images, tables and formatting from other programs. So you maybe need some validation with javascript to check the content before get the size.

---

**Second**:

Use an input type text and paste the content into an invisible div. And you can see the width of the invisible div.

```js
var elemDiv = document.getElementById('a'),
  elemInput = document.getElementById('b');

elemInput.oninput = function() {
  elemDiv.innerText = elemInput.value;
  console.log(elemDiv.clientWidth + 'px');
}
```

```css
.div {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<input id='b' type='text'>
<div id='a' class='div'></div>
```

**Note** : For this way, you must have the **same font** and **font size** on `input` and `div` tags.

Comment: This allows pasting images, tables and formatting from other programs. Contenteditable is everything but trivial.

Comment: @LeonAdler Right, I post another way, to get more choice.

Answer (score 12):

I have modified Chillers answer slightly, because it looks like you wanted the width rather than the letter count. I have created a span, which is absolute positioned off the screen. I am then adding the value of the input to it and then getting the width of the span. To make it more fancy you could create the span with javascript.

Note that the input and the span would have to have the same CSS styling for this to be accurate.

```js
document.getElementById("txtid").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  var mrspan = document.getElementById("mrspan");
  mrspan.innerText = this.value;
  console.log(mrspan.offsetWidth + "px");
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtid">
<span id="mrspan" style="position:absolute;left:-100%;"></span>
```

Comment: Downvoted, This opens the possibility for an HTML injection attack, use `innerText` instead of `innerHTML` for user provided data

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @Ferrybig I'm curious to know how?

Comment: I think it has something to do with InnerText stripping out any HTML tags e.g. someone could enter a malicious code `<script>if(theirMoney > myMoney) { return theirMoney; }</script>`;

Comment: `keyup` is probably not enough -- I just tried to paste something using the mouse. `innerText` should not only fix security issues, but also make the code work correctly if the message is e.g. "a <b> c" which would render as a much shorter HTML.

Comment: If the size of the text entered is larger than the size of the screen, the text will appear. You can put the "span" on the right instead of the left.

Comment: @WizardCoder When you are reading its value, yes, the content is converted to text, removing the tags. But when writing its value, the tags are *escaped*, not removed.

Answer (score 11):

Canvas `measureText()` method can be helpful in such a case. Call the following function whenever you need to get your text width:

```
function measureMyInputText() {
    var input = document.getElementById("txtid");
    var c = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var txtWidth = ctx.measureText(input.value).width;

    return txtWidth;
}
```

For more accurate result, you may set font styling to the canvas, especially if you set some font properties to the input. Use the following function to get the input font:

```
 function font(element) {
     var prop = ["font-style", "font-variant", "font-weight", "font-size", "font-family"];
     var font = "";
     for (var x in prop)
         font += window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue(prop[x]) + " ";

     return font;
 }
```

Then, add this line to the frist function:

```
ctx.font = font(input);
```

Comment: Add 'letter-spacing' to list of props?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE**

> Two things I want to put forward
>
> - Doing display none will not give you any `offsetWidth` if we are trying using vanilla JS. we can use `visibility: hidden;` or
>     `opacity:0` for that.
> - we need to add `overflow:auto` to the hidden `span` or else the text will be warped to the next line  if it exceeds the browser window
>     width and the width will stay fixed (*width of window*)

**OLD**

You can try this approach

Add a span and hide it

`<span id="value"></span>`

and then `onkeyup` add the text of the `textfield` on your hidden span and get its width.

**WITH THE HELP OF JQUERY**

**SNIPPET** (*UPDATED*)

```js
function update(elm,value) {
     $('#value').text(value);
     var width =   $('#value').width();
     $('#result').text('The width of '+ value +' is '+width +'px');
   
}
```

```css
#value{
  display:none;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" oninput='update(this,this.value)'>
<span id="value"></span>
<div id="result"></div>
```

**USING JS ONLY**

**SNIPPET** (*UPDATED*)

```js
function update(elm,value) {
     var span = document.getElementById('value');
     span.innerHTML = value;    
     var width = span.offsetWidth;
     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'The width of '+ value +' is '+ width+ 'px';
   
}
```

```css
#value{
  opacity:0;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" oninput='update(this,this.value)'>
<span id="value"></span>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: If enter 1 in the text box I get "The length is of is 0".

Comment: it's working now but the user wants using javascript.

Comment: you are pasting it not typing

Comment: @nadir-lasker Caught if fixed this issue it would be perfect.

Comment: You can use onchange event for that

Comment: @NadirLaskar I think the event [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput) is more appropriate

Comment: Yes you could use that too

Answer (score 4):

Using the above solution, I turned it into a single function.

```
let getWidth = (fontSize, value) => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerText = value;
  div.style.fontSize = fontSize;
  div.style.width = 'auto';
  div.style.display = 'inline-block';
  div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  div.style.position = 'fixed';
  div.style.overflow = 'auto';
  document.body.append(div)
  let width = div.clientWidth;
  div.remove();
  return width;
};
getWidth('10px', 'test');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach:

I create a fake 'span' element, which copies all font styles of the input element, then measures it's width

```js
function measureInputValueWidth(input: HTMLInputElement): number {
  const span = document.createElement("span");
  span.style.whiteSpace = "pre";
  span.style.fontFamily = input.style.fontFamily;
  span.style.fontSize = input.style.fontSize;
  span.style.fontWeight = input.style.fontWeight;
  span.style.fontStyle = input.style.fontStyle;
  span.style.letterSpacing = input.style.letterSpacing;
  span.style.textTransform = input.style.textTransform;
  span.style.padding = input.style.padding;
  span.style.margin = input.style.margin;
  span.style.border = input.style.border;
  span.style.boxSizing = input.style.boxSizing;
  span.style.position = "absolute";
  span.style.left = "-9999px";
  span.style.top = "-9999px";
  span.innerText = input.value;
  document.body.appendChild(span);
  const width = span.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  document.body.removeChild(span);
  return width;
}

function updateInputWidthToMatchValue(input: HTMLInputElement) {
  input.style.width = `${measureInputValueWidth(input)}px`;
}
```